# Permission error in HDFS when using pure python external library in AWS Glue

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs, aws-glue

I tried to run a customized Python script that imports an external pure python library (psycopg2) on AWS Glue but failed. I checked the CloudWatch log and found out the reason for the failure is that:

Spark failed the permission check on several folders in HDFS, one of them contains the external python library I uploaded to S3 (s3://path/to/psycopg2) which requires -x permission:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1507598924170_0002/psycopg2":root:hadoop:drw-r--r--
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:320)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:219)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1728)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1712)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPathAccess(FSDirectory.java:1686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirStatAndListingOp.getListingInt(FSDirStatAndListingOp.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListing(FSNamesystem.java:4486)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getListing(NameNodeRpcServer.java:999)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:634)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)
```

I make sure that the library contains only .py file as instructed in the AWS documentation.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem. AccessControlException on my python library directory

Answer (score 0):

You have a **directory** that doesn't have execute permission.  In a Unix-based O/S directories must have the execute bit set (for at least the user) to be usable.

Run something like

`sudo chmod +x /user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1507598924170_0002/psycopg2`

and try it again.

Comment: AWS Glue is managing the Spark cluster and HDFS behind the scene. All I can do is provide an S3 path to the python library I uploaded. How can I configure S3 so that when the library gets loaded into the cluster it will have +x permission

Comment: @Jasper_Li did you ever figure this out?   I have a simple python file in a directory and I get error when try to include specifying the s3 directory "org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/root/.sparkStaging/application_1535720663846_0001/includes":root:hadoop:drw-r--r--"

Comment: I was able to get it to work.  I was referring to the S3 directory.  Once referred to a py file in the s3 directory or even a zip file that included a python script in the s3 directory, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Glue only support's python only libraries i.e. without any specific native library bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The package psycopg2 is not pure Python, so it will not work with Glue.  From the setup.py:

> If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install
>   the PyPI 'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

From the [AWS Glue documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html):

> You can use Python extension
>   modules and libraries with your AWS Glue ETL scripts as long as they
>   are written in pure Python. C libraries such as pandas are not
>   supported at the present time, nor are extensions written in other
>   languages.